# Specificity at different thresholds (in the same way as sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I would like to get the specificities in the same way as precisions and recalls is given by `precision_recall_curve`.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
precisions, recalls, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(
    ground_truth,
    predictions,
)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @PV8 sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve gives me the precision and recall values at different thresholds. I would like to also/instead get the specificity/"true negative rate" in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I looked at the source code for `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve` (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e90b897768fd360ef855cb46e0b37f2b6faaf72/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py) and altered it to fit my needs.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.ranking import _binary_clf_curve

def specificity_sensitivity_curve(y_true, probas_pred):
    """
    Compute specificity-sensitivity pairs for different probability thresholds.
    For reference, see 'precision_recall_curve'
    """
    fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(y_true, probas_pred)
    sensitivity = tps / tps[-1]
    specificity = (fps[-1] - fps) / fps[-1]
    last_ind = tps.searchsorted(tps[-1])
    sl = slice(last_ind, None, -1)
    return np.r_[specificity[sl], 1], np.r_[sensitivity[sl], 0], thresholds[sl]
```